# Powershell to Create a zip (or 7z) of each file in a folder then delete original file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, batch-processing, 7zip

I have a folder with a Ton of iso images. I've found that a lot of the images have dummy data in them to reach the size of the original DVD. I can save an enormous amount of space by zipping them up.  I tried creating a batch file but it failed to work properly.

So, I basically want it to create a .7z for each file in a folder, then delete the original file.

Here's what I got. It zips the files but it fails on removable of the files afterwards. Can't figure out why:

```
function zipFiles()
 {
 dir *.iso| ForEach-Object { & "7z.exe" a -mx9 $_.BaseName $_.Name } 
 }

function delFiles()
 {
 dir *.iso| ForEach-Object { & Remove-Item $_.BaseName $_.Name } 
 }

zipFiles
delFiles
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pushd C:\...[path to folder]
for /r %%a in (*) do (
if "%%~xa"==".iso" (
7z a "%%~na.zip" "%%~a"
if exist "%%~na.zip" (
Del "%%~na.iso"
)
)
)
popd
```

Note: I seriously recommend putting an `Echo` before the `7z` and `Del` Commands to see what the program will do before running it. If you notice I made it only compress `.iso` files.

Lastly I would recommend using this program instead:

```
pushd C:\...[path to folder]
7z a Images.zip *.iso
Echo.&Echo Check all the files are compressed
pause
del *.iso
popd
```

Which will compress them all into 1 `.zip` file which can be opened in explorer and indivdual files can still be accesed. It will also improve the compression ratio. And again I recommend first checking all files are compressed before continuing in the middle pause command.

Look at the `7-zip.chm` file for more help in the 7-zip folder.

Comment: I need them all in separate ISO's. I'm running Hyperspin which uncompresses the game from the archive then mounts it in to deamon tools so the emulator can read from it. By archiving the ISO's it would save me about 2tb.

Comment: You first worked, EXCEPT: You had it delete the zip file after it actually created it. By changing if exist "%%~na.zip" to if exist "%%~na.iso" Del ... it worked just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, sorry about that, but happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-force` to the `remove-item`

Answer (score 0):

Change your *delFiles* function:

```
function delFiles()
 {
     dir *.iso| ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution is here:

[Superuser - 7-Zip script to delete after zipping](https://superuser.com/questions/629035/7zip-compress-the-contents-of-each-folder-in-a-directory)